# Como criar um popunder para quando alguém clicar em qualquer parte do site, abrir uma nova guia com outro site?

Tags: javascript

Olá! Alguém sabe como criar um popunder para quando uma pessoa clicar em qualquer parte do site/blog abrir uma nova guia com outro site? Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 3):

Função javascript

```
var popunder="http://site.com/"
function loadpopunder(){
win2=window.open(popunder)
win2.blur()
window.focus()
}
```

chamamos essa função no evento onclick da tag de abertura body

```
    <body onclick="loadpopunder()">
```

> Caso queira abrir um site randomicamente faça um array com os sites desejados na var popunder

```
var popunder=new Array()
popunder[0]="http://www....."
popunder[1]="http://www....."
popunder[2]="http://www....."
popunder[3]="http://...."
popunder[4]="http://...." 
//acrescente qtos elementos queira
```

> e substitua a variável win2 na função popunder por
>   win2=window.open(popunder[Math.floor(Math.random()*(popunder.length))])

Comment: Seria interessante você editar sua pergunta e explicar um pouco seu código.